# Is it possible to change Elasticsearch basic license to OSS

Tags: elasticsearch, licensing

I'd like to change the license but couldn't find the solution.
Is there any way to change Elasticsearch basic license to Elasticsearch OSS?
I know how to move OSS to basic but not reverse?

I haven't tried yet.

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I mean what is wrong with the default license?

Comment: It's Elasticsearch 7.16.3. 
I'm planning to migrate Elasticsearch to Opensearch and I've heard Opensearch only support OSS migration.

Comment: Also Opensearch forked at 7.10.2, so you need to be aware that any new features that came out between 7.10.2 and 7.16.3 and that you're using won't be present in Opensearch.

Comment: Hello, @NoahLee! I faced same issue while migration process from Elasticsearch to Opensearch. Especially with Kibana index. Did you find the way to do that?